# R: Comma in string interfering with new column

Tags: r

I am trying to move specific values from a row into a column.

Data Set:

```
table<- structure(list(V1 = c(1931432L, 1931432L, 1931434L, 1931434L, 1931434L), V2 = c(9548326L, 9548327L, 9551339L, 9551338L, 9551337L), V3 = c("D", "N", "N", "D", "D"), V4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V6 = c("This belongs in column 1", "This belongs in column 2", "This belongs in column 1", "This belongs in, column 2", "This belongs in column 3")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Currently my code:

```
tableNEW <-subset(table, select = c(1,2,6))
tableEND <- aggregate(.~ V1, data=tableNEW, FUN=function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse="|"))
```

is producing:

```
   V1     | V2                         | V3
1|1931432 |9548326, 9548327            | "This belongs in column 1", "This belongs in column 2"
2|1931434 |9551339, 9551338, 9551337   | "This belongs in column 1", "This belongs in, column 2", "This belongs in column 3"
```

Ideally, I am seeking:

```
   V1     | V2                         | V3                        |V4                        |V5
1|1931432 |9548326, 9548327            | "This belongs in column 1"| "This belongs in column 2"|
2|1931434 |9551339, 9551338, 9551337   | "This belongs in column 1"| "This belongs in, column 2"| "This belongs in column 3"
```

I have tried other methods that attempt to work after what is being produced, however the bloody comma in [2,V3] magically appears that messes the splitting up. I need to retain the commas inside the text as in the final table.

Is there an efficient method, to combine the collapse step with the column creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(reshape2)
res1 <- aggregate(V2~V1, data=tableNEW, FUN=paste, collapse=",")
tableNEW$indx <- with(tableNEW, ave(V1, V1, FUN=seq_along))
res2 <- setNames(merge(res1, dcast(tableNEW, V1~indx, value.var="V6")), paste0("V",1:5))
res2
#       V1                      V2                       V3
#1 1931432         9548326,9548327 This belongs in column 1
#2 1931434 9551339,9551338,9551337 This belongs in column 1
#                         V4                       V5
#1  This belongs in column 2                     <NA>
#2 This belongs in, column 2 This belongs in column 3
```

Comment: +1 I like this `seq_along` use with `ave` but also `setNames`. Things that I never use. So nice. Thank you for proposing this.

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps try to work on `table`
Like:

`table$V6 = gsub(',', '', table$V6)`

Rest of code will stay the same.